# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 breaking mysqlclient pip package

Tags: mysql-python, ubuntu-20.04

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 307, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/usman/gluu-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Before the upgrade I had no issues with mysqlclient. When trying to run my django environment I get this error.Any one else facing the same problem?
I have tried everything I could find online but nothing has worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this by running following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```